# Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields display field not working in loop

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields with Wordpress.
I have a custom post type called VIDEOS which has two fields - **video_link** and **video_artist**.

I can call and output the **video_link** field, but I cannot seem to display the '**video_artist**' field using the code below...

```
<?php 
   $posts = get_posts(array(
   'post_type'          => 'videos',
   'posts_per_page'     => -1
   )
   ));                  
   if( $posts ): ?>
<?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 
   setup_postdata( $post )                  
   ?>
<?php echo wp_oembed_get( get_field( 'video_link' ) ); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_field('video_artist'); ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**In fact, this line...**

```
<?php the_field('video_artist'); ?>
```

**...breaks the site and displays nothing at all after it appears. No html of any kind.**

Comment: Try [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/): `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_artist', true); ?>`.

Comment: Have you tried var_dump on the $posts variable? Also, if you go into your database, you may want to double check the actual meta value (that would be the best way to fully confirm that the correct field name is video_artist. The way I would do it is get your post's ID, go into MySQL (or phpMyAdmin) and try "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = '{YOUR_ID}'" and it will output all of the meta fields for that post. You can 100% confirm if you should be seeing a value and if the meta key is correct. That should get you started.

Comment: Just did a var-dump and no mention of video_artist field at all. @MillerMedia

Comment: Maybe there is no custom field with name `video_artist`. Add simple check: `<?php if (get_field('video_artist')) the_field('video_artist'); ?>`. [Here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/#usage) is details.

Comment: a check just prints out the word 'array' for every post.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = '{YOUR_ID}'" Will Not Help. post-meta is cached in the loop. Querying the DB will return all current and deleted post-meta - not just the current meta-data. So you end up with list of all post meta that has ever been on that post. Trust me... bad idea.

Comment: @admcfadn, that's not what I was getting at though. If the post had cached video_artist meta it would still show up in the loop so if OP looks in the DB and doesn't even see a video_artist field then that's the problem (it doesn't exist). It doesn't 'cache' all meta data. If the meta field for that post has been updated, then it updates that meta key's value in the DB (it doesn't save the previous value). Trust me... :p

Comment: @MillerMedia Gotcha, & 100% appreciate your point. I wanted to alert people to the problem all the same. I wasn't saying the loop caches all the meta-data. I meant that: a) When you modify meta data, it creates a new row with the updated value. b) The WordPress loop sorts the current meta from the old. I was referring specifically to ACF meta-data. With the acf-repeater field the primary key changes every time a new field is added & deleted ones are not removed.

Comment: @MillerMedia  I had to say something, because what's in the db is not always what's output in the loop (querying only by the post id could return false positives, confusing lowercase's situation even further) This thread addresses the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980496/get-advanced-custom-fields-repeater-field-value-based-off-of-another-repeater-va  I trust you ;P

Answer (score 2):

It's more or less the same code as your, just tested, and it works fine

As @admcfadn said, your are note in a wordpress loop, so you need to add the post id as a parameter of `the_field`

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'          => 'videos',
    'posts_per_page'     => -1
));       


if( $posts ): 

    foreach( $posts as $post ): 
        setup_postdata( $post );               


        the_title(); 

        the_field('video_link', $post->ID);

        the_field('video_artist', $post->ID);

     endforeach;
     wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
```

If you like to use the loop without arg in `the_field` that will look like that:

```
$options = array(
    'post_type'          => 'videos',
    'posts_per_page'     => -1
);

$query = new WP_Query( $options );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 

    the_title(); 

    the_field('video_link');

    the_field('video_artist');

endwhile; endif;
```

ps: you don't need to use `<?php`  `?>` on each line

Comment: Thanks for helping. So your code works BUT it only shows the most recent post. How do I make it show every post? If I have 200 posts I want it to show all 200, not just 1.

Comment: Actually, no code at all is rendered on the page immediately after the first value. so the entire site, footer/rest of page are just blank in the code now.

Comment: The 2 versions with `post_per_page => -1` will display all your video post. You can set this value to 200 to limit it at 200.

Comment: It should have an issue in your code, but without more information, i can't help you

Answer (score 0):

```
$post->the_field('video_artist');
```

you're using get_posts, not wp_query, so you might need to refer to the variables via $post.

&/or troubleshoot it with the following:

```
the_field('video_artist', $post->ID);
```

might get if for you.

Or...

```
$baz = get_field( 'video_artist' ); echo $baz;
```

Also, looks like you're missing a semi-colon after setup_postdata( $post ) and have an extra closing parentheses after get_posts

Comment: the_field('video_artist', $post->ID); should get if for you.

Comment: or... $baz = get_field( 'video_artist' ); echo $baz; ?

Comment: you're also missing a semi-colon after setup_postdata( $post )

Comment: this too just outputs the word 'array' instead of the field content for each post.

Comment: you can use print_r() or var_dump() on an array to find out what's inside. This one should work: the_field('video_artist', $post->ID); Are you using a repeater-field?

Comment: no it isn't a repeater field but it is a post relationship field. is that what is having an impact on this? and the var_dump does not show anything about the field i am trying to show.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109604/discussion-between-lowercase-and-admcfadn).